# I don't understand why I'm getting QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I've been looking at other StackOverflow questions regarding this error (and elsewhere on the web) but I don't understanding how the answers relate to my code. So, I'm hoping for either a fixed example that makes sense to me, or a better explanation of how and when events occur.

The code below was intended to figure out the dimensions of the screen it's running on, resize to that and draw a circle in the center that occupies most of the available screen real estate. It tried to do a lot more, but I've stripped it down -- enough, I hope. Now it just tries to draw a circle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *


class Viewport(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Viewport, self).__init__(parent)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(Viewport, self).paintEvent(event)

        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        square = QRect(10, 10, 30, 30)
        qp.drawEllipse(square)
        qp.end()


class UI(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UI, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = Viewport(self)
        gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(gridLayout)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(UI, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.view.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
        self.view.setFixedSize(400, 400)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

ui = UI()
ui.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above was stripped out of broken code that had a moving SVG item and the circle originally had a gradient fill. The SVG item was displaying and moving okay but the circle never showed up.

The gradient-filled circle worked fine in another program when it was in a drawn by a paintEvent for a QGroupBox, but I cannot grok how QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView work.

**UPDATED**

The error message, exactly as I see it (sadly w/o line numbers):

```
$ ./StackOverflow.py
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

Comment: I can't run the code right now, can you indicate at what line the exception gets raised? Also, confirm that you get the exception with the code exactly as you posted.

Comment: Please prepare a minimal, running example showing the error. Right now the code does not run because of some other, probably unrelated problems.

Comment: Odd. I posted exactly what I'm running and I have now attached the only error message I get. (And I was doing my best to make it a minimal running example. I stripped a LOT out of it.)  But I'll see what else I can get rid of to get the same error.

Comment: I stripped a bit more from the code above. I'm still getting the same error message I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to paint on the `viewport()`:

```
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(Viewport, self).paintEvent(event)

        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self.viewport())

        square = QRect(10, 10, 30, 30)
        qp.drawEllipse(square)
        qp.end()
```